# Proof Concerning Indexed family of Sets and Intervals

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory, real-numbers

I have been stuck on the following problem for some time. [image]

I know to prove two things are equal, you use the proof where you show they are both subsets. I think I was able to show that the set on the left, (which I called A) is a subset of the interval through simple logic, but to show the converse I am having some issues.

I attached my working thus far for anyone to look at it, but please note that after the line " $ \Leftrightarrow \alpha \geq -1 = \alpha + 1 \geq 0 and  \alpha \leq -2 ....$" the rest is tata (lol- but an attempt to work towards what I know would be the end of the proof, showing that a belongs also to A)

I have tried using the hint, but then I end up with something along the lines of '$n > \alpha + 1$ so  $n + 1 > \alpha$', which does not bring me closer to either -x, or x+1 of the interval on the left.

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to show that

$$\bigcap_{x>1}(-x,x+1]=[-1,2]\,.$$

Suppose first that $x>1$; then $x+1>2$, as you said. It’s not true, however, that $-x>-1$: rather, $-x<-1$, because the inequality is reversed when you multiply both sides by a negative number. It follows that $(-x,x+1]\supseteq[-1,2]$, and since this is the case for every $x>1$, we’ve shown that

$$\bigcap_{x>1}(-x,x+1]\supseteq[-1,2]\,.$$

Now we have to show that

$$\bigcap_{x>1}(-x,x+1]\subseteq[-1,2]\,;$$

this is the part for which the hint is intended. We want to show that if

$$y\in\bigcap_{x>1}(-x,x+1]\,,$$

then $y\in[-1,2]$, but the hypothesis that $y$ is in each of the intervals $(-x,x+1]$ for $x>1$ is hard to work with directly. It’s easier to show the contrapositive: if $y\notin[-1,2]$, then

$$y\notin\bigcap_{x>1}(-x,x+1]\,.$$

Suppose, then, that $y\notin[-1,2]$; then either $y<-1$, or $y>2$. I’ll do the first case and leave the second for you.

Suppose that $y<-1$, and let $u=-y$. Then $y=-u$, and $u>1$, so

$$y\notin(y,-y+1]=(-u,u+1]\supseteq\bigcap_{x>1}(-x,x+1]\,,$$

as desired, and it follows that

$$\bigcap_{x>1}(-x,x+1]=[-1,2]\,.$$

Comment: Hi, is it possible that you can explain why you made that substitution between y and u ? I am not sure why you did it.

Comment: @KAch: To make it more obvious that $(y,-y+1]$ is one of the intervals $(-x,x+1]$ whose intersection is being taken. Specifically, it’s the one with $x=-y$. I couldn’t simply let $x=-y$, however, because in $\bigcap_{x\>1}(-x,x+1]$ I’m using $x$ for the index variable, so it already has a meaning. In other words, $(y,-y+1]$ is the interval $(-x,x+1]$ when $x=u$.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification! Much appreciated (:

Comment: @KAch: You’re welcome!

Answer (score 0):

I tried the case with y>2 and got
y >2 $\iff$ y-1>1. letting b= y-1 $\implies$ (-(y-1), y] = (-b, b+1] which would imply that y$\in$ (-(y-1), y] = (-b,b+1]. Thus, it is possible for y$\notin$ [-1,2] but y$\in$ U$_{x>1}$ for all x. This would disprove the statment. Am I going wrong?

Comment: Hey, I just worked it out and I think it’s okay. I don’t see an error in the part of the proof the way you did it.